# Property names with dots Jackson JSON Parsing

Tags: java, json, serialization, annotations, jackson

I'm trying to use @JsonProperty to name a property with dots.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Compare {

@JsonProperty("test.total")
public HitsTotal total;

public HitsTotal getHitsTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setHitsTotal(HitsTotal hitsTotal) {
    this.total = hitsTotal;
}
}
```

When the serialization/deserialization happens, I don't see the property test.total.
It shows hitsTotal instead. 
What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe I made this mistake! But it'll be useful for someone who can accidentally run into this, nevertheless!
This is problem with not using Jackson Mapper for serialization.

Was doing serialization using

```
JSONObject(new Compare())
```

Need to use Jackson Mapper instead

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
JSONObject(om.writeValueAsString(new Compare()))
```